# Overview research on ambiguity of words

Tags: natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

As far as I know vector representations of word embeddings do not account for ambiguity. A single word can have different meanings f.e. "hot" can mean very good looking or very warm. Another example is "jaguar", that might refer to a car or an animal but the word is still represented by **one vector** while it has **two or more meanings**.

What methods take ambiguity into account? What approaches have been developed? What are the state of the art practices?
A clear overview on this research topic would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The keywords you can Google are "word sense induction" you can find a lot of articles on the subject there.

Comment: @Bar Thanks for sharing that, it indeed looks like what I need.

Comment: Take a look at [Topical Word Embeddings](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI15/paper/view/9314).  Also see the papers it references.

Comment: Also see the video lecture [Advanced word vector representations: language models, softmax, single layer networks](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/syllabus.html), starting from minute 62 or so.